# Tesseract 5.2.0 is giving exception access violation error due to corrupt memory (Windows Service)

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, tesseract

I am using Tesseract 5.2.0 for extracting text from image, images are inside pdf page. Everything is working fine but for some images I am getting **Access Violation Error Due To Corrupt Memory** at  **using (Pix img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imageFile))**.

Below is code for extracting text from image.
NOTE: This code is in window service project.

```
public static string ExtractTextFromImage(byte[] image)
        {
            if (image.Length == 0) return string.Empty;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string location = @"D:\Project\TextTessFramework";
            string tessData = Path.Combine(location, @"tessdata");
            using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(tessData, "eng+fra", EngineMode.Default))
            {
                string imageFile = $"temp_image.png";

                File.WriteAllBytes(imageFile, image);
                try
                {
                    using (Pix img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imageFile))
                    {
                        using (Page recognizedPage = engine.Process(img))
                        {
                            string recognizedText = recognizedPage.GetText().Trim();
                            sb.Append(recognizedText);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Image is not in proper format.");
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (File.Exists(imageFile))
                        File.Delete(imageFile);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Above code is working well for many pdf files. But there is some issue with 2-4 files when running inside windows service. When I tried to replicate this inside console project using same code for the problematic files, I am not facing any error.

Interesting part is when Access Violation occurs window service stops working, without going in catch block. Enabling native debugging I found that it gives message as:

**Cannot access memory (memory location) tesseract50.dll.**